# How to run native SQL queries in the same Hibernate transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, transactions

We have a Service which is `@Stateful`. Most of the Data-Operations are atomic, but within a certain set of functions We want to run multiple `native queries` within one transaction.

We injected the `EntityManager` with a transaction scoped persistence context. When creating a "bunch" of normal Entities, using `em.persist()` everything is working fine.

But when using native queries (some tables are not represented by any `@Entity`) Hibernate does not run them within the same transaction but basically uses ONE transaction per query.

So, I already tried to use manual `START TRANSACTION;`  and `COMMIT;` entries - but that seems to interfere with the transactions, hibernate is using to persist Entities, when mixing native queries and persistence calls.

```
@Stateful
class Service{

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "service")
   private EntityManager em;

   public void doSth(){
      this.em.createNativeQuery("blabla").executeUpdate();
      this.em.persist(SomeEntity);
      this.em.createNativeQuery("blablubb").executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

Everything inside this method should happen within one transaction. Is this possible with Hibernate?
When debugging it, it is clearly visible that every statement happens "independent" of any transaction. (I.e. Changes are flushed to the database right after every statement.)

---

I've tested the bellow given example with a minimum setup in order to eliminate any other factors on the problem (Strings are just for breakpoints to review the database after each query):

```
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class TestService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "test")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public void transactionalCreation(){
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','c')").executeUpdate();
        String x = "test";
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','c','b')").executeUpdate();
        String y = "test2";
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('c','b','a')").executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Hibernate is configured like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="test">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/test</jta-data-source>
        
        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
                
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
          <property name="connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

And the outcome is the same as with autocommit mode: After every native query, the database (reviewing content from a second connection) is updated immediately.

---

The idea of using the transaction in a manual way leads to the same result:

```
public void transactionalCreation(){
        Session s = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        Session s2 = s.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s2.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        s2.getTransaction().begin();
        
        s2.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','c')").executeUpdate();
        String x = "test";
        s2.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','c','b')").executeUpdate();
        String y = "test2";
        s2.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('c','b','a')").executeUpdate();
        
        s2.getTransaction().commit();
        s2.close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12969520/2749837) way already?

Comment: as an alternative you  can try to stop hibernate from flushing changes to the db by calling getSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL) before, but thats just a guess.

Comment: thx for your response. `FlushMode.Manual` doesn't have any impact it seems. I will try the proposed solution about the direct usage of a session rather then the `em`.

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't use [container managed transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) then you need to add the transaction policy too:

```
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRED)
```

I have only seen this phenomenon in two situations:

- the `DataSource` is running in auto-commit mode, hence each statement is executed in a separate transaction
- the `EntityManager` was not configured with `@Transactional`, but then only queries can be run since any DML operation would end-up throwing a transaction required exception.

Let's recap you have set the following Hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=JTA
transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
jta.UserTransaction=java:comp/UserTransaction
```

Where the final property must be set with your Application Server UserTransaction JNDI naming key.

You could also use the:

```
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

or some other strategy according to your current Java EE Application Server.

Comment: Yes, Hibernate is running in auto-commit mode. It is configured to use the JbossTransactionManager as well. I tried already - as mentioned in the coment - to set FlushMode to Manual for a certain method, which had no effect so far. I will try to add the Transaction policy as well, and update my post with the result.

Comment: But you shouldn't run in auto-commit. Hibernate should control the transaction commit or rollback.

Comment: I tested your proposed solution, but even with a minimum setup (see updated post) Every query runs independent. (I also played around with various annotations on the `transactionalCreation()` method, couldn't achieve anything so far... Can you tell for sure, that this *is* possible using `nateiveQuery()`?

Comment: You don't have two open two sessions. The first session already enlists a database connection, so the typical flow is one Session per thread. Use the first Session only, or even the entityManager. It should use the same connection for all queries executing in the same unit of work.

Comment: thx for your help so far. I just used a second Session to make sure that there is nothing "preconfigured" on it, which might cause unexpected results. but the Outcome is the same...

Answer (score 3):

After reading about the topic for another bunch of hours while playing around with every configuration property and/or annotation I could find a working solution for my usecase. It might not be the best or only solution, but since the question has received some bookmarks and upvotes, i'd like to share what i have so far:

At first, there was no way to get it working as expected when running the persistence-unit in managed mode. (`<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">` - JTA is default if no value given.)

I decided to add another persistence-unit to the persistence xml, which is configured to run in unmanaged mode: `<persistence-unit name="test2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">`.

(Note: The waring about *Multiple Persistence Units* is just cause eclipse can't handle. It has no functional impact at all)

The unmanaged persitence-context requires local configuration of the database, since it is no longer container-provided:

```
<persistence-unit name="test2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>test.AEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

A change required to the project would now be, that you add an `unitName`, whenever you use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to retrieve a managed instance of the EntityManager.

But be aware, that you can only use `@PersistenceContext` for the managed persistence-unit. For the unmanaged one, you could implement a simple `Producer` and Inject the EntityManager using CDI whenever required:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    static {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test2");
    }

    @Produces
    public static EntityManager createEm(){
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Now, in the example given in the original Post, you need to Inject the EntityManager and **manually** take care about transactions.

```
@Stateful
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public void transactionalCreation() throws Exception {

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        try {
            em.createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','a')")
                    .executeUpdate();
            em.createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','b')")
                    .executeUpdate();
            em.createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','c')")
                    .executeUpdate();
            em.createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','d')")
                    .executeUpdate();

            AEntity a = new AEntity();
            a.setName("TestEntity1");
            em.persist(a);

            // force unique key violation, rollback should appear.
//          em.createNativeQuery(
//                  "INSERT INTO `ttest` (`name`,`state`,`constraintCol`)VALUES('a','b','d')")
//                  .executeUpdate();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

My tests so far showed that mixing of native queries and persistence calls lead to the desired result: Either everything is commited or the transaction is rolledback as a whole.

For now, the solution seems to work. I will continue to validate it's functionality in the main project and check if there are any other sideeffects.

Another thing I need to verify is if it would be save to:

- Inject both Versions of the EM into one Bean and mix usage. (First checks seem to work, even when using both ems at the same time on the same table(s))
- Having both Versions of the EM operating on the same datasource. (Same data source would most likely be no problem, same tables I assume could lead to unexpected problems.)

ps.: This is *Draft 1*. I will continue to improve the answer and point out problems and/or drawbacks I'm going to find.

Comment: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<hibernate.connection.release_mode key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />` to your properties. After a restart should the Transaction handling work.