# IDENTITY_INSERT with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to insert some fake data into an SQL Server Express database. I am using some simple code like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "People")
public class Peeps implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "Decimal(10,0)")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
    private String name;

}
```

I call the entity manager to create the above class as follows:

```
private EntityManager em = createManager();
private EntityTransaction utx = em.getTransaction();

final Peeps entity = new Peeps();
entity.setId("10002");
entity.setName("Joe");
utx.begin();
em.persist(entity);
utx.commit();
```

However, when doing this, I get an error::

```
 Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'People' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

So what I tried doing is something like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON").executeUpdate();
em.persist(entity);
em.createNativeQuery("SET IDENTITY_INSERT People OFF").executeUpdate();
```

However, I still get the same error. My intuition leads me to believe that the connection is not being shared. Is there something I can do to instruct hibernate to set **IDENTITY_INSERT** to **ON** before I invoke my persistence?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to explicitly set the identifier for the entity or can you just allow the database to handle that for you?

Comment: @Naros Honestly, looking at some of my logic, my entity will never be written to the database in production code. Hence, the default strategy, I believe, requires for the identifier to be manually entered by the database. With that in mind, I have added this @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) to my entity, to allow the table to generate that id and give it back to the entity once we commit. Do you think this is a good strategy?

Comment: Some related discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746509/hibernate-nativequery-transaction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the next line under your id field:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

So your id field should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "People")
public class Peeps implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "Decimal(10,0)")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
    private String name;

}
```

Second, you are not supposed to set an ID to your entity by yourself, the ID will be generated automatically when you'll persist it using hibernate.

so get rid of: `entity.setId("10002");`

and just do this:

```
private EntityManager em = createManager();
private EntityTransaction utx = em.getTransaction();

final Peeps entity = new Peeps();
entity.setName("Joe");
utx.begin();
em.persist(entity);
utx.commit();
```

something else make sure that you configured your primary key in your DB table, with auto increment.

Comment: using the generated value annotation will only rely on the table that the entity relates for the setting of id's correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking

Comment: that the table must assign the primary key and return it? Attempting to understand the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#IDENTITY

Comment: It says that: "Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using database identity column."   the persistence provider = Hibernate, so it actually saying that: Indicates that Hibernate must assign primary keys for the entity using database identity column.

Comment: hmm i see. is this only for inserting records?

Comment: @MosheArad actually you just deleted explicit ID setting, which what angryip actually wants, and which causes an error. So you don't answer the question.